# Project vertex on a line

Tags: unity, 3d, 3d-meshes

[image]

V,A and B are 3 points in 3D space and We have d0 (distance of V from (AB)line).

I want to calculate question mark point in the image above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
Vector3 direction = ( B - A ).normalized;

Vector3 projection = A + direction * Vector3.Dot( direction, V - A);
```

Or here's an ever-so-slightly mathier version that saves a square root (you probably won't see a performance difference though unless you're doing this thousands of times in a cache-friendly inner loop)

```
Vector3 AtoB = B - A;

Vector3 projection = A + AtoB * Dot(AtoB, V - A)/AtoB.sqrMagnitude;
```

Comment: 3 line answers FTW.

Comment: Great! You saved my day!